# PGR_Djikstra function error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, postgis-2.0

I'm trying to find a shortest path between 2 nodes using djikstra method but it keeps saying

> ERROR:  Error, query must return columns 'id', 'source', 'target' and 'cost'

this is my query:

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid, source,target, ST_Length(geom2d) as cost FROM  public.canada_rail_net', 1, 200, false, false);
```

is there anything wrong with column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's your gid

Do

```
   SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
       FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT gid As id, source,target, ST_Length(geom2d) as cost 
         FROM  public.canada_rail_net', 1, 200, false, false);
```

Comment: If you are not sure about your answer, write a comment rather than an answer with few words. Please edit your answer or post it as a comment.

Comment: well it fixed my problem :)

Comment: okay I've updated so it's a complete sql statement :)